AMBER fails to generate parameters
I'm new to computational chemistry, and I'm trying to model the enzyme EGFR and a molecule named lapatinib with AMBER. I got a .pdb file of Lapatinib attached to EGFR, and a .sdf file of lapatinib itself from the pdb site. The names of the files are: EGFR_FMM.pdb and FMM_ideal.sdf
I get an error when I do the exactly same thing in the tutorial. The commands are a bit long, so I'll paste it one by one.
Note: I'm running AmberTools on my school server, so nohup was used.
(base) hjs@kepler:~/MD/testEGFR$ ls
EGFR_FMM.pdb  FMM_ideal.sdf

(AMBER) hjs@kepler:~/MD/testEGFR$ nohup antechamber -i FMM_ideal.sdf -fi sdf -o FMM.mol2 -fo mol2 -c bcc -s 2
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

(AMBER) hjs@kepler:~/MD/testEGFR$ parmchk2 -i FMM.mol2 -f mol2 -o FMM.frcmod

(AMBER) hjs@kepler:~/MD/testEGFR$ tleap -f oldff/leaprc.ff99SB
-I: Adding /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/prep to search path.
-I: Adding /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib to search path.
-I: Adding /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/parm to search path.
-I: Adding /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/cmd to search path.
-f: Source oldff/leaprc.ff99SB.

Welcome to LEaP!
(no leaprc in search path)
Sourcing: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/cmd/oldff/leaprc.ff99SB
Log file: ./leap.log
Loading parameters: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/parm/parm99.dat
Reading title:
PARM99 for DNA,RNA,AA, organic molecules, Polariz.& LP incl.02/04/99
Loading parameters: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/parm/frcmod.ff99SB
Reading force field modification type file (frcmod)
Reading title:
Modification/update of parm99.dat (Hornak & Simmerling)
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/all_nucleic94.lib
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/all_amino94.lib
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/all_aminoct94.lib
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/all_aminont94.lib
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/ions94.lib
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/solvents.lib

> source leaprc.gaff
----- Source: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/cmd/leaprc.gaff
----- Source of /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/cmd/leaprc.gaff done
Log file: ./leap.log
Loading parameters: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/parm/gaff.dat
Reading title:
AMBER General Force Field for organic molecules (Version 1.81, May 2017)

> FMM=loadmol2 FMM.mol2
Loading Mol2 file: ./FMM.mol2
Reading MOLECULE named MOL

> check FMM
Checking 'FMM'....
Checking parameters for unit 'FMM'.
Checking for bond parameters.
Checking for angle parameters.
Unit is OK.

> loadamberparams FMM.frcmod
Loading parameters: ./FMM.frcmod
Reading force field modification type file (frcmod)
Reading title:
Remark line goes here

> saveoff FMM FMM.lib
 Creating FMM.lib
Building topology.
Building atom parameters.

> saveamberparm FMM FMM.prmtop FMM.rst7
Checking Unit.
Building topology.
Building atom parameters.
Building bond parameters.
Building angle parameters.
Building proper torsion parameters.
Building improper torsion parameters.
 total 25 improper torsions applied
Building H-Bond parameters.
Incorporating Non-Bonded adjustments.
Not Marking per-residue atom chain types.
Marking per-residue atom chain types.
  (Residues lacking connect0/connect1 - 
   these don't have chain types marked:

    res total affected

    MOL 1
  )
 (no restraints)
> quit
    Quit


(AMBER) hjs@kepler:~/MD/testEGFR$ pdb4amber -i EGFR_FMM.pdb -o aug_EGFR_FMM.pdb --reduce --dry

==================================================
Summary of pdb4amber for: EGFR_FMM.pdb
===================================================
REDUCE returned non-zero exit status: See reduce_info.log for more details

----------Chains
The following (original) chains have been found:
A

---------- Alternate Locations (Original Residues!))

The following residues had alternate locations:
None
-----------Non-standard-resnames
PO4, FMM

---------- Missing heavy atom(s)

LYS_12 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
ARG_43 misses 6 heavy atom(s)
GLU_44 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
LYS_45 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
LYS_48 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
GLU_49 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
ASN_99 misses 3 heavy atom(s)
GLU_157 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
LYS_158 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
VAL_159 misses 2 heavy atom(s)
MET_228 misses 3 heavy atom(s)
ARG_245 misses 6 heavy atom(s)
GLU_268 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
ARG_269 misses 6 heavy atom(s)
SER_271 misses 1 heavy atom(s)
ARG_275 misses 6 heavy atom(s)
GLU_280 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
VAL_281 misses 2 heavy atom(s)
VAL_282 misses 2 heavy atom(s)
GLU_286 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
LEU_288 misses 3 heavy atom(s)
ILE_289 misses 3 heavy atom(s)

(AMBER) hjs@kepler:~/MD/testEGFR$ tleap -f oldff/leaprc.ff99SB
-I: Adding /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/prep to search path.
-I: Adding /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib to search path.
-I: Adding /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/parm to search path.
-I: Adding /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/cmd to search path.
-f: Source oldff/leaprc.ff99SB.

Welcome to LEaP!
(no leaprc in search path)
Sourcing: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/cmd/oldff/leaprc.ff99SB
Log file: ./leap.log
Loading parameters: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/parm/parm99.dat
Reading title:
PARM99 for DNA,RNA,AA, organic molecules, Polariz.& LP incl.02/04/99
Loading parameters: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/parm/frcmod.ff99SB
Reading force field modification type file (frcmod)
Reading title:
Modification/update of parm99.dat (Hornak & Simmerling)
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/all_nucleic94.lib
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/all_amino94.lib
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/all_aminoct94.lib
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/all_aminont94.lib
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/ions94.lib
Loading library: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/lib/solvents.lib
> source leaprc.gaff
----- Source: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/cmd/leaprc.gaff
----- Source of /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/cmd/leaprc.gaff done
Log file: ./leap.log
Loading parameters: /home/hjs/MD/amber24/dat/leap/parm/gaff.dat
Reading title:
AMBER General Force Field for organic molecules (Version 1.81, May 2017)
> loadamberparams FMM.frcmod
Loading parameters: ./FMM.frcmod
Reading force field modification type file (frcmod)
Reading title:
Remark line goes here
> loadoff FMM.lib
Loading library: ./FMM.lib

> complex = loadpdb aug_EGFR_FMM.pdb
Loading PDB file: ./aug_EGFR_FMM.pdb

Warning: Unknown residue: PO4   number: 289   type: Terminal/beginning
..relaxing end constraints to try for a dbase match

Warning:   -no luck

Warning: Unknown residue: PO4   number: 290   type: Nonterminal
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LYS 12>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LYS 12>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LYS 12>.A<CE 14>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LYS 12>.A<NZ 17>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CPRO 32>.A<OXT 15>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 43>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 43>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 43>.A<NE 14>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 43>.A<CZ 16>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 43>.A<NH1 17>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 43>.A<NH2 20>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CGLU 44>.A<OXT 16>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CGLU 44>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CGLU 44>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CGLU 44>.A<OE1 12>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CGLU 44>.A<OE2 13>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<NLYS 45>.A<CG 10>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<NLYS 45>.A<CD 13>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<NLYS 45>.A<CE 16>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<NLYS 45>.A<NZ 19>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LYS 48>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LYS 48>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LYS 48>.A<CE 14>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LYS 48>.A<NZ 17>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 49>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 49>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 49>.A<OE1 12>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 49>.A<OE2 13>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ASN 99>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ASN 99>.A<OD1 9>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ASN 99>.A<ND2 10>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 157>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 157>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 157>.A<OE1 12>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 157>.A<OE2 13>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CLYS 158>.A<OXT 23>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CLYS 158>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CLYS 158>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CLYS 158>.A<CE 14>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CLYS 158>.A<NZ 17>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<NVAL 159>.A<CG1 9>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<NVAL 159>.A<CG2 13>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MET 228>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MET 228>.A<SD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MET 228>.A<CE 12>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 245>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 245>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 245>.A<NE 14>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 245>.A<CZ 16>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 245>.A<NH1 17>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 245>.A<NH2 20>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 268>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 268>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 268>.A<OE1 12>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 268>.A<OE2 13>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 269>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 269>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 269>.A<NE 14>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 269>.A<CZ 16>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 269>.A<NH1 17>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 269>.A<NH2 20>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CMET 270>.A<OXT 18>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<NSER 271>.A<OG 10>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 275>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 275>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 275>.A<NE 14>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 275>.A<CZ 16>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 275>.A<NH1 17>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<ARG 275>.A<NH2 20>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CGLU 280>.A<OXT 16>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CGLU 280>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CGLU 280>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CGLU 280>.A<OE1 12>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CGLU 280>.A<OE2 13>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<NVAL 281>.A<CG1 9>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<NVAL 281>.A<CG2 13>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<VAL 282>.A<CG1 7>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<VAL 282>.A<CG2 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 286>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 286>.A<CD 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 286>.A<OE1 12>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<GLU 286>.A<OE2 13>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LEU 288>.A<CG 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LEU 288>.A<CD1 10>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<LEU 288>.A<CD2 14>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CILE 289>.A<OXT 20>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CILE 289>.A<CG2 7>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CILE 289>.A<CG1 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<CILE 289>.A<CD1 14>
Creating new UNIT for residue: PO4 sequence: 290
Created a new atom named: P within residue: .R<PO4 290>
Created a new atom named: O1 within residue: .R<PO4 290>
Created a new atom named: O2 within residue: .R<PO4 290>
Created a new atom named: O3 within residue: .R<PO4 290>
Created a new atom named: O4 within residue: .R<PO4 290>
Creating new UNIT for residue: PO4 sequence: 291
Created a new atom named: P within residue: .R<PO4 291>
Created a new atom named: O1 within residue: .R<PO4 291>
Created a new atom named: O2 within residue: .R<PO4 291>
Created a new atom named: O3 within residue: .R<PO4 291>
Created a new atom named: O4 within residue: .R<PO4 291>
Created a new atom named: S2 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: N7 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: O13 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: N18 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: N20 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: N22 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: O27 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: C30 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: C31 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: C32 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: C33 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: F34 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: C35 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: C36 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: CL3 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: C38 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: C39 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: C40 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H282 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H281 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H11A within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: HN7 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H82 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H81 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H62 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H61 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H52 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H51 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H40 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H38 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H35 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H32 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H31 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
Created a new atom named: H30 within residue: .R<MOL 292>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<C27 38>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<C22 31>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<C20 29>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<C18 26>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<N4 22>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<C13 19>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<N2 18>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<N3 20>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<C7 11>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<C4 8>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<N1 7>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<C3 6>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<C2 5>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<S1 2>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<O1 3>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<O2 4>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<Cl1 37>
  Added missing heavy atom: .R<MOL 292>.A<F1 34>
  total atoms in file: 4553
  Leap added 303 missing atoms according to residue templates:
       107 Heavy
       196 H / lone pairs
  The file contained 44 atoms not in residue templates
> saveamberparm complex EGFR_FMM.prmtop EGFR_FMM.rst7
Checking Unit.

Warning: There is a bond of 8.634 angstroms between C27 and H25 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C27 38> and .R<MOL 292>.A<H25 65>

Warning: There is a bond of 8.390 angstroms between C26 and C27 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C26 36> and .R<MOL 292>.A<C27 38>

Warning: There is a bond of 3.186 angstroms between C22 and H22 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C22 31> and .R<MOL 292>.A<H22 62>

Warning: There is a bond of 3.044 angstroms between C21 and C22 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C21 30> and .R<MOL 292>.A<C22 31>

Warning: There is a bond of 5.064 angstroms between C20 and C21 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C20 29> and .R<MOL 292>.A<C21 30>

Warning: There is a bond of 6.175 angstroms between C19 and C20 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C19 28> and .R<MOL 292>.A<C20 29>

Warning: There is a bond of 14.597 angstroms between O4 and C19 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<O4 27> and .R<MOL 292>.A<C19 28>

Warning: There is a bond of 16.928 angstroms between C18 and O4 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C18 26> and .R<MOL 292>.A<O4 27>

Warning: There is a bond of 7.803 angstroms between C17 and C18 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C17 25> and .R<MOL 292>.A<C18 26>

Warning: There is a bond of 10.542 angstroms between C14 and C28 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C14 21> and .R<MOL 292>.A<C28 39>

Warning: There is a bond of 11.292 angstroms between C12 and C28 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C12 17> and .R<MOL 292>.A<C28 39>

Warning: There is a bond of 5.296 angstroms between C10 and H13 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C10 15> and .R<MOL 292>.A<H13 53>

Warning: There is a bond of 12.750 angstroms between C9 and C29 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C9 14> and .R<MOL 292>.A<C29 40>

Warning: There is a bond of 5.666 angstroms between C8 and O3 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C8 12> and .R<MOL 292>.A<O3 13>

Warning: There is a bond of 7.070 angstroms between C7 and H12 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C7 11> and .R<MOL 292>.A<H12 52>

Warning: There is a bond of 3.237 angstroms between C6 and C7 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C6 10> and .R<MOL 292>.A<C7 11>

Warning: There is a bond of 5.532 angstroms between C6 and H11 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C6 10> and .R<MOL 292>.A<H11 51>

Warning: There is a bond of 5.927 angstroms between C4 and H10 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C4 8> and .R<MOL 292>.A<H10 50>

Warning: There is a bond of 6.057 angstroms between C1 and S1 atoms:
-------  .R<MOL 292>.A<C1 1> and .R<MOL 292>.A<S1 2>
FATAL:  Atom .R<PO4 290>.A<P 1> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<PO4 290>.A<O1 2> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<PO4 290>.A<O2 3> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<PO4 290>.A<O3 4> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<PO4 290>.A<O4 5> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<PO4 291>.A<P 1> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<PO4 291>.A<O1 2> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<PO4 291>.A<O2 3> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<PO4 291>.A<O3 4> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<PO4 291>.A<O4 5> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<S2 67> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<N7 68> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<O13 69> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<N18 70> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<N20 71> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<N22 72> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<O27 73> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<C30 74> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<C31 75> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<C32 76> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<C33 77> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<F34 78> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<C35 79> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<C36 80> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<CL3 81> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<C38 82> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<C39 83> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<C40 84> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H282 85> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H281 86> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H11A 87> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<HN7 88> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H82 89> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H81 90> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H62 91> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H61 92> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H52 93> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H51 94> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H40 95> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H38 96> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H35 97> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H32 98> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H31 99> does not have a type.
FATAL:  Atom .R<MOL 292>.A<H30 100> does not have a type.

Error: Failed to generate parameters

Warning: Parameter file was not saved.
> quit
    Quit


I think something went wrong with the EGFR_FMM.pdb file, but I can't fix it. How do I solve this problem?
EDIT)) I think the pdb file was not ready for the calculation. Here are the results for pdb4amber:
==================================================
Summary of pdb4amber for: EGFR_FMM.pdb
===================================================
REDUCE returned non-zero exit status: See reduce_info.log for more details

----------Chains
The following (original) chains have been found:
A

---------- Alternate Locations (Original Residues!))

The following residues had alternate locations:
None
-----------Non-standard-resnames
FMM, PO4

---------- Missing heavy atom(s)

LYS_12 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
ARG_43 misses 6 heavy atom(s)
GLU_44 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
LYS_45 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
LYS_48 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
GLU_49 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
ASN_99 misses 3 heavy atom(s)
GLU_157 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
LYS_158 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
VAL_159 misses 2 heavy atom(s)
MET_228 misses 3 heavy atom(s)
ARG_245 misses 6 heavy atom(s)
GLU_268 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
ARG_269 misses 6 heavy atom(s)
SER_271 misses 1 heavy atom(s)
ARG_275 misses 6 heavy atom(s)
GLU_280 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
VAL_281 misses 2 heavy atom(s)
VAL_282 misses 2 heavy atom(s)
GLU_286 misses 4 heavy atom(s)
LEU_288 misses 3 heavy atom(s)
ILE_289 misses 3 heavy atom(s)

